# Timestamps calculated at different times are the same for python3.6

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to calculate the timestamps at different times. On the linux server, I call the package time that comes with python, but the timestamps of 2:00 a.m. on April 15, 1990 and 3:00 a.m. on April 15, 1990 are the same Yes, I want to ask if it is the problem of the python package itself, thank you

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

$import time
$time.mktime(time.strptime(str('1990-04-15 02:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
$640116000.0
$time.mktime(time.strptime(str('1990-04-15 03:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
$640116000.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I'll bet that was the day when we changed to Daylight Saving Time. So 2am becomes 3am.

Comment: In Python 3.10 I get `640155600.0` and `640159200.0`, respectively

Comment: Which time zone is the machine you run this on configured to use? Since you don't set any time zone in the code, keep in mind that Python will assume local time (in most cases...), not UTC. This is not specific to the Python version btw.